# ProGuard in Android is not working.(not obfuscating)

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate my simple HelloWorld project (that I just created) with ProGuard.

The configuration files are below.

[**project.properties**]

> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
>
> target=android-20

[**proguard-project.txt**]

Nothing valid. all the lines are commented.

Lastly, I created signed apk file through the menu, File - Export - Export Android Application,
with a new key.

To make sure that the apk is obfuscated properly, I unzip the apk and decompiled classes.dex to view the inner class files. but NOT obfuscated at all. all the function names in MainActivity.java are
still the same.

Anything I missed out?

Thank you.

Comment: I fount out it not obfuscated. the default MainActivity.java seems not obfuscated. after I add new class named Testit.java, it hopefully turned out obfuscating.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what files Proguard is using to configure itself.  In the sdk proguard directory there is also a proguard-android.txt and a proguard-android-optimize.txt.  The proguard-project.txt in the project directory is commented out.  A tutorial overview with current file structures would be welcome.  The Android development documentation talks about a proguard.cfg file that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the "Enabling ProGuard" section at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html to see exactly how ProGuard determines which configuration file(s) to use.  Look carefully at the different ways to specify the file(s) for Eclipse builds vs. Android Studio (or Gradle) builds.  The ProGuard configuration files delivered with the SDK are simple starting points (examples) that almost certainly will not do exactly what you want.  You should copy them to an appropriate location and change them as needed for your particular needs.